# Mysql query gets extremely slow when using union, is there any other way to avoid union, or increase the efficiency of the query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

We've got 2 tables in our project, one for warehouse stock in, and one for out. But now we need to put them together in one query, which of course comes with query conditions like 'time','warehouse_id',etc., the result needs to be sorted as well. The solution was to union these 2 tables, and then sort, the query looks like:

```
select * from
(select ... from warehouse_in left join ... where ... 
union
select ... from warehouse_out left join ... where ...) as tmp order by 'stock_time' limit X,Y
```

But the problem is that this query runs extremely slow, it takes 1.5s to execute on less than 100k records, which usually take less than 0.05s if we don't use union.
Is there any other way to improve the query speed?

Comment: Two suggestions: First, do you really need to use `UNION` here, or could you live with `UNION ALL`?  The latter is more performant, because it frees MySQL from having to remove duplicates.  Second, the next thing to look at is optimizing the selects in both halves of the union.  Have you run `EXPLAIN` on your query yet?

Comment: I tried `UNION ALL`, but it didn't improve much. And each half of the union works fine when they are alone.

Comment: Please provide the full query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like poor indexes.  Also, will there be dup rows?  If not, switch to `UNION ALL`; it is _probably_ faster.

Comment: Consider storing ins and outs in a single table , e.g. 'warehouse_transactions', and with a column stating whether the direction of movement.

Comment: Thank you all for answering, a single big table could work, i'll try this. Besides, I found another solution which is to sort and limit in each half of the query with a parameter of last_record_time, and then union the result and do sort and limit again. I prefer to build a single table.

Comment: Right. It's your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` on the results of the UNION that's causing your performance problem. Your solution, to do the limiting separately on the two sides of the union, is correct. This question really should not have been closed; it's clear from your query what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering, a single big table could work, i'll try this. Besides, I found another solution which is to sort and limit in each half of the query with a parameter of last_record_time, and then union the result and do sort and limit again. I prefer to build a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` unless you are expecting duplicate rows.  `UNION` does a de-dup pass over the data.

Add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT Z` to the inner queries.  Z=X+Y.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or